# Multi-button mouse / mmo mouse with Linux support

Tags: drivers, mouse

My Logitech G600 recently developed a double-click problem after about 1.5 year of use and I think it's time for a new mouse.

I use Linux primarily, and I'd like to get a mouse with at least 10 buttons that has native Linux support. Currently my G600 works well with Linux but if I want to remap the keys or change some settings I need to log back into Windows. So I'm looking for something that has a native Linux app.

I'm open to all brands, does anyone know if such mice exist?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`libratbag`'s hardware database](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/blob/master/hwdb/70-libratbag-mouse.hwdb); this shows which devices are supported by `libratbag`, which allows gaming features to be managed (including profiles, buttons etc.). It's still early in its life, but it is useful to determine how usable a given mouse is likely to be. (To actually configure a mouse, you'd use [`ratbagd`](https://github.com/libratbag/ratbagd) and its associated `ratbagctl`, and [Piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper).)

Currently supported devices include some Etekcity mice, many Logitech mice, some Roccat mice and G.Skill's MX-780. Razer mice aren't supported, and that appears unlikely to change. Your G600 probably would work, if the appropriate identifiers were added to the hardware database!

This obviously doesn't replace hands-on experience. I can ask `libratbag`'s author, he has quite a collection now...

Comment: Mostly supports the G600 as of today; doesn't support the GShift mode properly yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the libratbag device database and whilst there is an entry for G600, it's just a placeholder entry.

I've stumbled upon this project on github today and this looks much more promising. You do have to login to the Logitech Gaming Software on Windows / OSX first and ensure some mouse buttons are set to default before compiling/running the script on Linux.

https://github.com/mafik/logitech-g600-linux